# Unable to Update text from fragment in data binding

Tags: android, data-binding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">    
    <data>
 <import type="com.demo.Model" />
 <variable
            name="model"
            type="Model" />
</data>
  <Textview
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                          
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLableBg"
    android:ems="10"                                                                           
    android:text="@={model.name}"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null/>
</layout>
```

Here is   fragment

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_authentication, container, false);
    Model model = getModel()// get model return model data from server
    binding.setModel(model);
    binding.text.setText("This is demo")
    }
```

I am getting data from **api** call and set the model.everything fine in case but when i set text its noting to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do set that value after setting model otherwise value will be overwrite.

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_authentication, container, false);
        Model model = getModel()// get model return model data from server

        binding.setModel(model);
        binding.getModel.setName("this is demo");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
Model model = getModel()// get model return model data from server
binding.setModel(model);
model.name.set("This is demo")
```

in your Model make sure name is:

```
public ObservableField<String> name = new ObservableField<>();
```